# How to clone a key in Amazon S3 using Python (and boto)?

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto

I have a file contained in a key in my S3 bucket. I want to create a new key, which will contain the same file. Is it possible to do without downloading that file?
I'm looking for a solution in Python (and preferably boto library).

Answer (score 16):

Where bucket is the destination bucket:

```
bucket.copy_key(new_key,source_bucket,source_key)
```

Comment: This actually reads the key and puts it up in the new bucket - which is not what you want.  Sorry.

Comment: I don't believe this is accurate. This is the best answer IMO. The `copy_key` method passes the `x-amz-copy-source` header in a PUT request, which tells S3 to copy directly from region to region, without downloading to your machine.

Comment: Here's them docs: http://boto.cloudhackers.com/en/latest/ref/s3.html#boto.s3.bucket.Bucket.copy_key

Answer (score 10):

```
from boto.s3.key import Key

#Get source key from bucket by name
source_key = source_bucket.get_key(source_key_name)

#Copy source key to a new bucket with a new key name (can be the same as source)
#Note: source_key is Key
source_key.copy(dest_bucket_name,dest_key_name)

#The signature of boto's Key class:
def copy(self, dst_bucket, dst_key, metadata=None,
             reduced_redundancy=False, preserve_acl=False,
             encrypt_key=False, validate_dst_bucket=True)

#set preserve_acl=True to copy the acl from the source key
```

Answer (score 4):

Browsing through boto's source code I found that the Key object has a "copy" method. Thanks for your suggestion about CopyObject operation.

Comment: Help on method copy in module boto.s3.key:

`copy(self, dst_bucket, dst_key, metadata=None, reduced_redundancy=False, preserve_acl=False, encrypt_key=False)` method of boto.s3.key.Key instance
    Copy this Key to another bucket.

Answer (score 2):

S3 allows object by object copy.
The CopyObject operation creates a copy of an object when you specify the key and bucket of a source object and the key and bucket of a target destination. 
Not sure if boto has a compact implementation.

Answer (score 2):

Although nobody asked, I thought it might be relevant to show how to do this with `simples3`:

```
>>> b.copy("my_bucket/file.txt", "file_copy.txt", acl="public")
```

I'm not sure what Boto does here, but it's worth noting that the permissions (ACL) will *not* be copied by S3, it will be reset to "private" if nothing else is specified. To copy the ACL, you have to ask for it first.

Comment: I second this comment regarding the permissions (after encountering a bug) `dest_bucket.copy_key(key.name, src_bucket_name, key.name, preserve_acl=True)`

Answer (score 0):

Note that the 'copy' method on the Key object has a "preserve_acl" parameter (False by default) that will copy the source's ACL to the destination object.