# AWS S3: Enable encryption through API/Script

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto

We have images stored in the AWS S3 for our production services.
Is there any API which will allow to enable encryption on these existing resources without downloading and uploading again?

I see [Boto module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1464961/how-to-clone-a-key-in-amazon-s3-using-python-and-boto) in Python allows to clone the key with additional parameters e.g encryption, but this will create a new key. As these keys are stored in a separate database, we want to retain existing keys but just enable encryption.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's some code that will convert all files in a bucket to use server-side encryption:

```py
import boto

conn = boto.connect_s3('REGION')
bucket = conn.get_bucket('BUCKET')

for k in bucket.list():
  bucket.copy_key(new_key_name=k.key, src_bucket_name=bucket.name, src_key_name=k.key, encrypt_key=True)
```

It copies to the same key name, but you might want to tweak it to preserve storage class, ACLs, etc.