# How can I change an S3 object's settings by "copying" to the same key?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I would like to change the [`server_side_encryption` settings](https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Object.server_side_encryption) for an S3 object (preferably using `boto3`).

As far as I understand I cannot actually change S3 object setting like this, and will instead need to "copy" the object with the new settings. Firstly, is this true? If so, is it possible to copy an S3 object to the same key (in one operation), thus overwriting the original file with a new file with new settings?

Answer (score 1):

AWS S3 objects cannot be modified once created. You cannot write to them in-place, append,etc. AWS does support changing an S3 object by copying it in-place while making the changes. Encryption falls into that category.

Here is a python example from John Rotenstein on how to encrypt files that are already in S3. Add a vote to John's answer it it helps you.

[Encypt existing files](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32879847/8016720)

John Rotenstein's example:

```
import boto

conn = boto.connect_s3('REGION')
bucket = conn.get_bucket('BUCKET')

for k in bucket.list():
  bucket.copy_key(new_key_name=k.key, src_bucket_name=bucket.name, src_key_name=k.key, encrypt_key=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can copy a file to itself to change the Server-Side encryption settings.

Here is a sample using the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/):

```
aws s3 cp s3://my-bucket/foo.txt s3://my-bucket/foo.txt --sse AES256
```